# Eclipse and MySQL

Tags: mysql, eclipse

How do I link up eclipse and mysql? I have already added the
mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar via
project>(right-click)>properties>Java Build Path>Libraries.

However each time I run my application, I am still getting the 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
error. Hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of application are you trying? Java Web or Java Standalone? Could you share the piece of code?

Comment: @JamesJithin It's a Java Web Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the mysql-connector jar, it is available for class compilations of your Project code. Usually the drivers would be loaded using reflection, i.e. through `Class.forName("driver_class_name_here")`. This happens during the run-time and compiler need not bother about what class name is being provided.

Usually the web-applications are packaged as war archives and deployed into the web-containers or servers. When the server executes on these archives, it expects the referred class in the classpath. The classpath includes many locations and one among them is the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of the archive.

When we build the web-archive through Eclipse or by using build tools like ant or maven, we need to specify what to be included inside the archive. On Eclipse, we do that through the `Deployment Assembly` tab on Project Properties.

For a web-project with the following structure:

[image]

We add the specific library to the archive through `Deployment Assembly` > `Add` > `Java Build Path Entries` > `Next`, select the libraries and say `Finish`. We specify that the mysql connector to be included into the archive as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

you still need to connect to your database

```
Connection conn;
java.sql.Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
String url;
String db = "databasename";
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + db + "";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
st = conn.createStatement();
String sqlquery = "enter your query";
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: It's a web application and I am using connection pooling. The context.xml file is placed in the WEB-INF folder. This same application runs without any problem in NetBeans, but in Eclipse I am having an issue. I suspect that my context.xml file is not being read when the application is deployed, because when I tried to simulate the same problem in netbeans by commenting out the <Resource> section of context.xml, I get the same error. I am not sure how to go about rectifying this.